# display diffrent timezones time in a page with php?

Tags: php

how can i display diffrent timezones time in a page with php?

like

```
Eastern:    02:23 AM
Central:    02:23 AM
Asia/India: 02:23 AM
Mountain:   02:23 AM
Pacific:    02:23 AM
```

Comment: if you know the time-zones you know the difference to your time-zone. just add the differece in hours.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the Search function before asking questions. Your question has been asked and [answered multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=different+timezones+php) in this or similar form before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $timezone)
{
    $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    echo $timezone . ': ' . $time->format('c').'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Tiny improvement suggestion: since you are just outputting the time, there is no need to instantiate a new DateTime object for each timezone. Instantiate the object before the loop and then just `$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
echo $tz->getName() . " - " . $date->format('H:m');
```